# How to integrate Sphinx 4 with Freeswitch, receive call audio and do some recognition

Tags: java, freeswitch, sphinx4

I have a working knowledge of setting IVR on Freeswitch. I have installed Sphinx 4 and it's working good for Speech captured from microphone. However I want to integrate FS with Sphinx 4.

I read somewhere it says that it requires some MRCP server like Cairo to integrate FS with SPHINX. Is something like Cairo really required? FS comes with PocketSphinx...but I want to use Sphinx 4. Please tell me how to integrate Sphinx4 and FreeSwitch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Zanzibar/Cairo/OpenIVR is a straightforward way to go. For Sphinx4 you can use freeswitch MRCP module together with MRCP server backed by CMUSphinx.

So your choices are:

- Unimrcp with pocketsphinx (preferred because already tested)
- Zanzibar MRCP server with sphinx4
- mod_pocketsphinx without MRCP (less standard solution)

Pocketsphinx is not very different than sphinx4, the accuracy is the same. The performance of pocketsphinx is slightly faster and the solution is already tested by Freeswitch developers. That's why pocketsphinx is preferred.

For more information see

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_openmrcp#UniMRCP_Server (MRCP plugin for freeswitch)

https://sourceforge.net/projects/openivr/ (Zanzibar)

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_pocketsphinx (direct integration with pocketsphinx)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Resource_Control_Protocol (Information about MRCP)

Comment: Can you tell how to integrate Cairo and Freeswitch?? Where do i specify configuration parameters for integrating Freeswitch and Cairo?? And how do i check integration?

Comment: Same way as any other server, you just run it and configure the server ip address in the mod_mrcp settings. Read for details http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_openmrcp#mrcp_profiles

Comment: I was testing my integration with demo program which comes with cairo.
It asks for SIP address of cairo...What it should be? In mod_mrcp settings i dont find any parameter which can assign cairo a user extension like 1000, 1002 etc.
I m assuming that my cairo server should have some sip address like
sip:1002@127.0.0.1. But where to specify 1002 as user extension for cairo??
In other words how should cairo register itself on freeswitch with user id as 1002??

Comment: Sip address doesn't necessary include the user, you might use something like sip:127.0.0.1 but if your MRCP server is configured in a special way you might want a user too.

Answer (score 0):

you can call external scripts from freeswitch dialplan, so I would suggest passing the control to a LUA or javascript or Perl script, prompt for user input, turn on recording, then pass the recorded file to Sphinx. Something like that should work (I never used Sphinx myself)

Comment: I want to do it on the fly...I mean i dont want to wait till user ends its recording. I want that Sphinx should perform recognition simulataneously for each words as user utters...